# GWT 2.5.1 CellTable and SimplePager issue

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT 2.5.1. I have a CellTable in which paging is done by SimplePager. I am seeing following issues with the SimplePager.

1. The number of rows displayed in the last page is incorrect. Let's say there are total 22 rows and the page size is set to 10. So, the third page should show 21-22 of 22. Instead, it shows 13-22 of 22. The last page always shows 10 rows, it takes some from the previous page.
2. There is no Last page button. There is a fast forward button which is also disabled.
3. When there is no data, the text says 1-1 of 0.

I know these are known issues as I did a lot of research on this topic. Wanted to know if this is still not fixed in GWT 2.5.1. Any wrappers that are available yet? Any workaround for this bug? 
I am writing my custom pager which extends SimplePager as below.

```
public class MySimplePager extends SimplePager {

    public MySimplePager() {
        this.setRangeLimited(true);
    }

    public MySimplePager(TextLocation location, Resources resources, boolean showFastForwardButton, int fastForwardRows, boolean showLastPageButton) {
        super(location, resources, showFastForwardButton, fastForwardRows, showLastPageButton);
        this.setRangeLimited(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPageStart(int index) {
        if (this.getDisplay() != null) {
          Range range = getDisplay().getVisibleRange();
          int pageSize = range.getLength();
          if (!isRangeLimited() && getDisplay().isRowCountExact()) {
            index = Math.min(index, getDisplay().getRowCount() - pageSize);
          }
          index = Math.max(0, index);
          if (index != range.getStart()) {
            getDisplay().setVisibleRange(index, pageSize);
          }
        }  
      }
}
```

I am instantiating the pager as:

```
SimplePager.Resources resources = GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class); 

usersPager = new MySimplePager(SimplePager.TextLocation.CENTER, resources, false,10, true);
```

But, this does not work at all. Strange thing is, the method setPageStart() is not being invoked at any point. I put some log messages in it, but they did not get displayed. Anything I am doing wrong here or missing?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Strange, that workaround works for me with GWT 2.5.1 and I do see the last page button. I wonder if it could be related to the table's dataProvider or the way it gets updated. Can you show the code for your CellTable class?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work at all? Instead of log statements just run in developer mode and put a break point at the first line of setPageStart.

Answer (score 0):

I don't face your first 2 problems. Third issue was there in 2.5.1 RC1 release but it has been rectified in the 2.5.1 release.

1) There are hacks to overcome this, but I forgot what is it.
2) Use the following constructor to enable fastforwardbutton and last page button

```
public SimplePager(TextLocation location, boolean showFastForwardButton,
      boolean showLastPageButton)
```

3) This is fixed in latest release.

[For more info check out this.](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable)